# Regex grep command to select only passwords that start with a number and end with a number

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to formulate a grep regex expression that selects only passwords that start with a number and ends with a number. The format of the txt file is:

password, #OfUsersWhoUseThisPassword

(*The comma is included*) for example:

```
123456, 25969
12345678, 8667
1234, 5786
qwerty, 5455
dragon, 4321
```

Comment: Is it possible to have `,` in the password ?

Comment: Please provide sample output

Comment: And your own attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
grep -oP '^\d.*?\d(?=,)' /tmp/file
```

- `-o` is to print only what is matching
- `-P` is to use [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) like regex

Check [*look around*](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444). Check [online with explanations](https://regex101.com/r/a6OUyO/4)

Answer (score 0):

Regex:

```
^[0-9]{1}.*[0-9]{1}(?=,)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/a6OUyO/3)

Comment: There's the comma at the end, I don't think this is what OP whant

Comment: You're right, should have used a positieve lookahead for that.